# 3 imagens diferentes com 3 botões para abrir o texto

Tags: javascript

3 imagens diferentes com 3 botões para abrir cada uma um texto diferente.Só funciona o primeiro botão e os textos do segundo e terceiro quando accionado o primeiro botão movimentam-se com o movimento do primeiro texto.
Já procurei em todo o lado e não encontro a solução.

Alguem me pode ajudar?

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var button = document.getElementById("show-more");

button.onclick = function() {
  if (content.className == "open") {
    content.className = "";
    button.innerHTML = "Ler Mais";

  } else {
    content.className = "open";
    button.innerHTML = "Fechar";
  }

};
```

```css
#content {
  width: 280px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin-left: 100px;
  max-height: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.7s;
}

#content.open {
  width: 280px;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 0.7s;
}

#show-more {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  margin-left: 210px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos.</div>
<div id="cont1">O Lorem programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="mark">Depois de ter o site
  <div class="mark">Depois de ter o O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de.
  </div>
  <a id="show-more">Show more</a>
  <a id="show.more1">Show more</a>
</div>
```

Temos tres imagens. Por baixo de cada uma há um botão para clicar a dizer "ler mais". Cada imagem tem o seu texto distinto. O texto só aparece quando se clica no botão.( diga-mos q o texto desenrola) O problema é que o texto da segunda imagem ao clicar no botão da primeira imagem, aparece tambem, mesmo sem ter nehnum comando e desloca-se para o final da pagina.Ja meti tudo em divs separadas,e não dá. Sem falar que cada vez que acrescento ao script um novo botão, deixa tudo de funcionar. Em suma, ja tentei tudo e ha algo que me está a falhar e não dou com o erro.

Comment: Fatima, podes explicar melhor a diferênça entre os botões e o que queres que eles façam? Podes clicar em [edit] e juntar essa informação à pergunta...

Comment: Tem de ser em javascript ou podera ser em jquery?

Comment: Nem entendi nesse código o que significa primeira e segunda imagem. Posta teu código mais completinho, por gentileza? Ou dê mais detalhes.

Comment: Pode ser em jquery não tem de ser em Javascript. Eu não coloquei tags das imagens porque o botão fica fora delas. Ou seja não é na imagem que se carrega e sim no botão do lado de fora.